# Set a default tabbing from the first text field in Jquery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jquery-ui-dialog

I have "add address" button, clicking on the button pops up a Jquery Dialog to fill address information with house number, Street, City , County, State, Country and Postal Code.
I would like to start my tabbing from house number but the focus always sets close button on the title bar.

```
        <f:view>
    <body onload="sartup()">
        <h:form id="form1">
            <h:panelGroup >
                <h:outputLabel value="House Number" styleClass="label" id="hnoLbl"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="hnoId" value="#{somebackingbean.address1}"></h:inputText>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputLabel value="Street" styleClass="label" id="streetLbl"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText  id="streetID" value="#{somebackingbean.address2}" ></h:inputText>
            </h:panelGroup>         
        </h:form>
    </body>
</f:view>
```

I tried setting focus using the following JavaScript:

```
    Function startup(){
    document.getElementById("form1:hnoLbl").triggerHandler("focus");
    }
```

and

```
     Function startup(){
    document.getElementById("form1:hnoLbl").focus();
    }
```

but it does not work. I prefer using keyboard would like the cursor to directly point at the first text field. What can I do to start tabbing from house number?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set it up when the dialog has opened, in the `open` event of the dialog:

```
$( "#yourdialog" ).dialog({
   open: function() {
      $("#form1:hnoLbl").focus();
   }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
According to your comments you cannot execute code from the open event, so try to give focus to the field on a `setTimeout()` call that fires once the dialog has already loaded, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById("form1:hnoLbl").focus();
}, 400); //adjust the duration accordingly if needed
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm using a common function to open dialog so can't edit that. Do you know any other way.

Comment: You can try giving focus using setTimeout() once the dialog has already loaded, so the dialog don't steal your focus. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I'm very glad it worked for you, you have enough reputation to give upvotes, so consider upvoting my answer too (up arrow) if you're happy with it :-)